# sympy solve vs. solveset vs. nsolve

Tags: sympy, solver

I am trying to solve the following equation for r:

```py
from sympy import pi, S, solve, solveset, nsolve, symbols

(n_go, P_l, T, gamma_w, P_g, r, R_mol) = symbols(
    'n_go, P_l, T, gamma_w, P_g, r, R_mol', real=True)

expr = -P_g + P_l - 3*R_mol*T*n_go/(4*r**3*pi) + 2*gamma_w/r
soln = solveset(expr, r, domain=S.Reals)
soln1 = solve(expr, r)
```

`soln` is of the form `Complement(Intersection(FiniteSet(...)))`, which I really don't know what to do with.
`soln1` is a list of 3 expressions, two of which are complex. In fact, if I substitute values for the symbols and compute the solutions for soln1, all are complex:

```py
vdict = {n_go: 1e-09, P_l: 101325, T: 300, gamma_w: 0.07168596252716256, P_g: 3534.48011713030, R_mol: 8.31451457896800}
for result in soln1:
    print(result.subs(vdict).n())
```

returns:

```
-9.17942953565355e-5 + 0.000158143657514283*I
-9.17942953565355e-5 - 0.000158143657514283*I
0.000182122477993494 + 1.23259516440783e-32*I
```

Interestingly, substituting values first and then using solveset() or solve() gives a real result:

```py
solveset(expr.subs(vdict), r, domain=S.Reals).n()
```

> {0.000182122477993494}

Conversely, nsolve fails with this equation, unless the starting point contains the first 7 significant digits of the solution(!):

```py
nsolve(expr.subs(vdict), r,0.000182122 )
```

> ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (9562985778.9619347103 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)

It should not be that hard, here is the plot:

[image]

My questions:

1. Why is `nsolve` so useless here?
2. How can I use the solution returned from `solveset` to compute any numerical solutions?
3. Why can I not obtain a real solution from `solve` if I solve first and then substitute values?

Comment: If I replace vdict by `{n_go: 1e-10, P_l: 3615, T: 300, gamma_w: 0.07168596252716256, P_g: 3531.98618872273, R_mol: 8.31451457896800}` in the above example, solve and solveset do not find any solutions, but the real part of `solve(expr, r)[2].subs(vdict)` corresponds to the root when I plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Maelstrom is good but I just want to add a few points.

The values you substitute are all floats and with those values the polynomial is ill-conditioned. That means that the form of the expression that you substitute into can affect the accuracy of the returned results. That is one reason why substituting values into the solution from solve does not necessarily give exactly the same value that you get from substituting before calling solve.

Also before you substitute the symbols it isn't possible for solve to know which of the three roots is real. That's why you get three solutions from `solve(expr, r)` and only one solution from `solve(expr.subs(vdict), r)`. The third solution which is real after the substitution is the same (ignoring the tiny imaginary part) as returned by solve after the substitution:

```
In [7]: soln1[2].subs(vdict).n()                                                                                                                              
Out[7]: 0.000182122477993494 + 1.23259516440783e-32⋅ⅈ

In [8]: solve(expr.subs(vdict), r)                                                                                                                            
Out[8]: [0.000182122477993494]
```

Because the polynomial is ill-conditioned and has a large gradient at the root `nsolve` has a hard time finding this root. However `nsolve` can find the root if given a narrow enough interval:

```
In [9]: nsolve(expr.subs(vdict), r, [0.0001821, 0.0001823])                                                                                                   
Out[9]: 0.000182122477993494
```

Since this is essentially a polynomial your best bet is actually to convert it to a polynomial and use `nroots`. The quickest way to do this is using `as_numer_denom` although in this case that introduces a spurious root at zero:

```
In [26]: Poly(expr.subs(vdict).as_numer_denom()[0], r).nroots()                                                                                               
Out[26]: [0, 0.000182122477993494, -9.17942953565356e-5 - 0.000158143657514284⋅ⅈ, -9.17942953565356e-5 + 0.000158143657514284⋅ⅈ]
```

Comment: Thank you, so the difference between substituting before or after solving is essentially due to rounding errors? If I managed to substitute into `soln` and evaluate, would it then give no solution, as all three are complex (see `soln1`)? I'll try the `Poly` approach.

Comment: Yes, `soln` should ideally evaluate on substitution. I think maybe `.evalf` doesn't quite work right with sets though. Also you would end up with the empty set because the real root would have a small imaginary part.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I have done some debugging and found that `.evalf` with sets works all right. The problem is that we have `...Intersection(<3 complex floats>, Reals)...` which returns `EmptySet`. Even `chop=True` does not help since this argument is lost along the way.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, @OscarBenjamin and @Maelstrom. Since the solution set given by `solveset` is currently not easy to work with, this answer was the most helpful to find a solution to my specific problem, which I described in a separate answer. Therefore, I will mark the answer by @OscarBenjamin as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your expr is essentially a cubic equation.

Applying the `subs` before or after solving should not substantially change anything.

### `soln`

`soln` is of the form `Complement(Intersection(FiniteSet(<3 cubic solutions>), Reals), FiniteSet(0))` i.e. a cubic solution on a real domain excluding 0.

The following should give you a simple `FiniteSet` back but `evalf` does not seem to be implemented well for sets.

```py
print(soln.subs(vdict).evalf())
```

Hopefully something will be done about it soon.

### 1

The reason why `nsolve` is not useful is because the graph is almost asymptotically vertical. According to your graph, the gradient is roughly 1.0e8. I don't think `nsolve` is useful for such steep graphs.

Plotting your substituted expression we get:
[image]
Zooming out we get:
[image]

This is a pretty wild function and I suspect `nsolve` uses an epsilon that is to large to be useful in this situation. To fix this, you could provide more reasonable numbers that are closer to 1 when substituting. (Consider providing different units of measurement. eg. instead of meters/year consider km/hour)

### 2

It is difficult to tell you how to deal with the output of `solveset` in general because every type of set needs to be dealt with in different ways. It's also not mathematically sensible since `soln.args[0].args[0].args[0]` should give the first cubic solution but it forgets that this must be real and nonzero.

You can use `args` or `preorder_traversal` or things to navigate the tree. Also reading documentation of various sets should help. `solve` and `solveset` need to be used "interactively" because there are lots of possible outputs with lots of ways to understand it.

### 3

I believe `soln1` has 3 solutions instead of 4 as you state. Otherwise, your loop would print 4 lines instead of 3. All of them are technically of complex (as is the nature with floats in Python). However, the third solution you provide has a very small imaginary component. To remove these kinds of finicky things, there is an argument called `chop` which should help:

```py
for result in soln1:
    print(result.subs(vdict).n(chop=True))
```

One of the results is `0.000182122477993494` which looks like your root.

Comment: Thank you!! So `soln.subs(vdict).evalf()` should be able to return a set of real results, right? Should I create an issue for this? Or could you? I don't really understand how the nested `Complement(Intersection(FiniteSet()))` construct is supposed to work.

Comment: @StanSchymanski yes, it should be able to return a set of real results. But it returns `EmptySet`. I think this is because when evaluating, we have 3 `complex` solutions that, when intersected with `Reals`, returns `EmptySet`. I'm not sure how to fix this without drastically changing SymPy's architecture. The nested construct is the same as its mathematical construct. You can `print(latex(expr))` and put it into a latex viewer to view any expr in a pretty way. I suggest also using a debugger while running so you can see what attributes are available to you during runtime to learn more.

Comment: I don't understand why you are getting an empty set. For me, `print(soln.subs(vdict).evalf())` returns: `Complement(Intersection(FiniteSet(-4.88704239859008e-7 - ...`

Comment: The Reals problem would be simple, I could just remove the `domain=S.Reals` from solveset, but in this example, I still don't get any numbers with `evalf()`.

Comment: @StanSchymanski Returning an empty set is a bug in SymPy and I am just letting you know that this specific case is not easy to fix. I think your plan of removing `domain=Reals` is a good work-around for now. You can then remove the complex numbers by hand afterwards.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough, but even if I remove `domain=Reals`, I get a `Complement(FiniteSet(-4.908e-7 - 0.027*450**(1/3)*(...))` instead of a set of numbers. So for me, `evalf()` does not seem to work on the solution of `solveset()`. Could you update your answer with an example that works?

Comment: @StanSchymanski You are correct in that `evalf()` does not really work well with some set operations like `Complement`. I could show you how to get the set that you want for this specific example but I cannot provide a method to do it for slightly different problems. I think it would be much more beneficial if someone makes set operations work with `evalf()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will create an issue for that and refer to here.

Comment: @StanSchymanski No need to worry, there is already an issue and PR on it. #20356 and #20321. However, a new PR is encouraged since I am unsure if I will get to all the issues raised here in a single PR.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unswer to the underlying question: **How to compute the roots of the above equation efficiently?**

Based on the suggestion by @OscarBenjamin, we can do even better and faster by using `Poly` and `roots` instead of `nroots`. Below, sympy computes in no time the roots of the equation for 100 different values of P_g, while keeping everything else constant:

```py
from sympy import pi, Poly, roots, solve, solveset, nsolve, nroots, symbols
(n_go, P_l, T, gamma_w, P_g, r, R_mol) = symbols(
    'n_go, P_l, T, gamma_w, P_g, r, R_mol', real=True)
vdict = {pi:pi.n(), n_go:1e-09, P_l:101325, T:300, gamma_w:0.0717, R_mol: 8.31451457896800}
expr = -P_g + P_l - 3*R_mol*T*n_go/(4*r**3*pi) + 2*gamma_w/r
expr_poly = Poly(expr.as_numer_denom()[0], n_go, P_l, T, gamma_w, P_g, r, R_mol, domain='RR[pi]')
result = [roots(expr_poly.subs(vdict).subs(P_g, val)).keys() for val in range(4000,4100)]
```

All that remains is to check if the solutions are fulfilling our conditions (positive, real). Thank you, @OscarBenjamin!

PS: Should I expand the topic above to include nroots and roots?